# Meteor Method Endlessly Runs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have this code in a Meteor.methods definition:

```
update_field: function(collection,document_id,field,value) {
    obj = {};
    obj[field] = value;
    console.log(obj);
    if (collection == 'clients') {
        var Collection = Clients;   
    } else if(collection = 'sites') {
        var Collection = Sites;
    }
    Collection.update(
    {
        _id: document_id
    }, {
        $set: obj
    }, function(error,id) {
        console.log(error,id);
        return(error,id);
    }
    );
}
```

This method is called from several client-side <strike>helpers</strike> events, and updates the field as needed. But whenever it runs once, it never stops running. Sometimes it runs infinitely even when all the `Meteor.call('update_field')`s have been commented out. I have tried including a 'caller' parameter and adding that to all the possible calls to figure out why it keeps getting called to no avail. Any ideas why this is looping?

Edit: this runs 2,000/minute

Edit2: this is called in one of two ways: on a keyup code==13 (enter) in an appropriate field or a field blur. However, event when these calls are commented out, the issue persists.

Comment: I'm gonna guess that something is reactively updating and causing this to re-run. Check around your code for helpers and other data contexts that might update reactively and that do so about the same amount as this guy runs.

Comment: @herrshuster It's generally a bad idea for your helpers to call methods - especially those that change state. See the "overworked helpers" section from [common mistakes](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes).

Comment: @DavidWeldon, is this the case for events as well? I updated my question to reflect that events are firing these calls. If so, do you have a suggestion as to how I would update a field once a connected input is blurred?

Comment: No, events should be fine in general.

Comment: Check out for the 'blur' event handler, which may bring back focus to the field, and then again blur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue was that one of my methods blurred the input field but preventDefaulted. Then the blur handler was called and caused the loop from there. This is my first Meteor project, so I'm chalking this one up to not quite understanding the system sufficiently. I still find it strange that the method was getting called when the callers were commented out, but I'll figure that one out another day.

Answer (score 1):

Especially your second comment worries me:

> However, even when these calls are commented out, the issue persists.

Then who is calling it? The behaviour you're describing points to some helper executing the method. The method changes some data, which re-executes the helper (reactivity) and we end up with a classic endless loop.

Check your entire source code for references to this method:

```
$ grep -r "update_field" *
```

Maybe you set a variable somehow and then use the variable to call the method. Also: Have you declared the method inside a `Meteor.methods({ ... })` block?